# How an emailprovider.db gets populated?

Tags: android

In an android email app the db emailprovider.db gets populated after fetching the values from the server when it is configured by using any of the protocols...in my case it is exchange server ..i wanted to know which class files are responsible for populating the data in the tables of emailprovider.db after fetching the data from the server.The source code used is Android 2.2.

Answer (score 0):

Look at LocalStore in the sources of the Email app:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Email/+/froyo-release/src/com/android/email/mail/store/LocalStore.java

Comment: Hi Peter..i looked into the mentioned class file and applied logs at appropriate places....but none of the logs got printed...am doing it wrt Eas protocol....can u give me an idea how the flow goes from booting of emulator till the db gets populated???

Comment: Sorry, you have to do your own debugging.

Comment: Hi Peter..i have been trying but have been stuck ...it would be really helpful if you give me an high level view of the data handling mechanism in entire operation using eas protocol...